# Загрузка файла на сервер CherryPy из клиента Python 3

Tags: python, cherrypy

Пытаюсь передать файл на сервер CherryPy из клиента на Python 3.

Клиентская часть:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload'
files = {'file.zip': open('file.zip', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.status_code == requests.codes.ok)
```

Серверная часть:

```
import os
import tempfile
import shutil

import cherrypy


config = {
    'global' : {
        'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port' : 8080,
        'server.thread_pool' : 8,
        'server.max_request_body_size' : 0,
        'server.socket_timeout' : 60
  }
}


class App:
    @cherrypy.config(**{'response.timeout': 3600})
    @cherrypy.expose()
    def upload(self):
        '''Handle non-multipart upload'''

        destination = os.path.join('/home/uvv/upload')
        with open(destination, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(cherrypy.request.body, f)

        return 'Okay'


if __name__ == '__main__':
        cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Соответственно сервер возвращает:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2016:11:38:49] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 2083 "" "python-requests/2.10.0"
```

А клиент: `False`

Не могу понять почему файл не загружается. Да права на папку `/home/uvv/upload` стоят `a+rwx` (поэтому проблема точно не в правах доступа)

Comment: 1) Файл загружается из клиента на тестовый сервер например на php.
2) Сервер принимает файл отправленный через post запрос тем же curl например?

Comment: @Igor при чём тут php?

Comment: Проверьте что находится в cherrypy.request.body. Класс App не от object ли должен наследоваться? Да и [судя по примеру](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.0/progguide/files/uploading.html) файл не в request находится

Comment: @FeroxTL php тут при том, что люди не пытаются разбираться, без раздельной проверки понять в чем причина очень сложно. На php нет ограничений как для python, в python в большинстве фреймфорков встроенная защита.

Comment: @Igor давайте больше конкретики. Ваше утверждение очень спорно. Чтобы мне не быть голословным, заявляю: по умолчанию защита включена только в django. Bottlepy - нет, flask - нет, cherrypy - нет. Голый python (wsgi) - нет. Где ваше большинство фреймворков с защитой?

Comment: @FeroxTL в чистом виде они редко используются. Возможно по защите не прав, но ошибок допускается очень много именно из-за незнания особенностей. Но в том что тестирование должно быть раздельным, проверенный сервер отдельно, проверенный клиент отдельно, это точно.

Answer (score 1):

Решение проверено под Ubuntu
Клиентская часть:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload'
files = {'ufile': open('file.zip', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.status_code == requests.codes.ok)
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

Серверная часть:

```
import os
import cherrypy

config = {
    'global' : {
        'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
        'server.socket_port' : 8080,
        'server.thread_pool' : 8,
        'server.max_request_body_size' : 0,
        'server.socket_timeout' : 60
    }
}


class App(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def upload(self, ufile):
        upload_path = os.path.normpath('/home/user/upload')
        upload_file = os.path.join(upload_path, ufile.filename)
        size = 0
        with open(upload_file, 'wb') as out:
            while True:
                data = ufile.file.read(8192)
                if not data:
                    break
                out.write(data)
                size += len(data)
        out = '''
length: {}
filename: {}
mime-type: {}
''' .format(size, ufile.filename, ufile.content_type, data)
        return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Путь '/home/user/upload' нужно поменять на свой.

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте загрузить файл с помощью curl
2. Посмотрите, чему именно равен код `r.status_code` (а не просто что он не равен `ok`).